# Why does the SEIS require a bellows type wind cover?

Tags: mars, probe, insight, instrument, seismology

The [Seismic Experiment for Interior Structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seismic_Experiment_for_Interior_Structure) probe onboard the Insight lander is meant to measure subtle seismic events on Martian surface.

In order to reduce the noise induced by wind, a protective cover is installed on top of it.

Is it essential for this cover to have a bellows design? Why would not a standard rigid cover do the job of wind protection?

Image for reference from Spaceflight 101's [InSight Instrument Overview](http://spaceflight101.com/insight/insight-instruments/) "Wind & Thermal Shield – Image: CNES/InSight Project" (courtesy @uhoh's [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/32347/511)).

[image: InSight's Seismometer's wind cover]

Answer (score 3):

1. The bellows are flexible, which means the cover will adjust itself to give a good seal on the uneven surface.
2. the bellows can be easily folded up to take up minimum volume during flight, without needing a powered unfolding sequence which would add complexity and weight.

Comment: The "chainmail on a rock" picture above illustrates your point #1 nicely.